Backward slashes are appended in JSON request body
I'm facing an issue in karate framework, while passing a variable to the JSON request body backward slashes are being appended, we want to remove all these auto appended slashes in order to get the exact response, so can anyone help me out here please?
My code:
* def skidList = lib.getNewSkidDetails(boxNo)
* def value1 = lib.modifyArrayList()
* print value1


(Printed text of value1 : "+235077584", "+231822952", "+233603365", "+234441350", "+233370169")

Given url 'https.example.com'
And path 'exampleservice/post'
And param action = 'receiving/receivingjson'
* def jsonString = {"skidTags":#(value1),"receivingAllocation":true}
And request value1
When method POST
Then status 200

After running above script below request body is being passed

{"skidTags":"["+235077584", "+231822952", "+233603365", "+234441350", "+233370169""],"receivingAllocation":true}

I tried below solutions but none of them worked for me!!
1.

def cleanString = value1.replace(/\/g, '').replace(/""/g, '"')





def cleanString = rawJson.replace('\\', '').replace('\"', '"')

And request cleanString
